# In Pose mode, how to deform softbody according to the collision caused by the movement of bones?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bones, pose-mode, collision, surface-deform

The mesh called "Cube" is supposed to be a soft body, which has been parented to 6 bones:

[image]

[image]

As the screenshot above shows, in *Pose mode*, when I rotate the bone, the mesh does not deform when the collision happens. How do I set up the collision and properly deform the mesh in *Pose mode*, according to the mesh collision?

(Method without using any physics simulation is preferred.)

[image]

Comment: The bones are used for deforming the mesh, but they do not make the mesh interact with each other. If you don't want to use softbody physics, I guess you will have to manually deform it and save it via shapekey or something like that or create additional extra bones to manually deform the mesh in those colliding areas...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thank you for commenting! I believe that instead of manually deforming, using geometry node can do this.... And, I also find that there may be an add-on which use something similar to the surface deformation modifier to deform the mesh when the collision happens. But it's not free: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvEI9yD0q-I

Comment: Since this site is about helping with problems in vanilla Blender and so only the officially shipped add-ons, I would not go and suggest to you buying some add-on. And especially when I do not own it myself and cannot tell anything about it. And well, _Geometry Nodes_ can probably do something like that, but I suspect it's a complex setup and not easy to answer by saying, do this, this and that. So maybe it would be best to find a tutorial on how to simulate collisions in _Geometry Nodes_. Or maybe someone else here has the time to build that for you...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann A geometry node tutorial about the collision I have found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dj-2xCb_GKs 
But I am not sure if it works in Pose mode.